# Raytracing - Rays shot from camera through screen don't deviate on the y axis - C++

Tags: c++, vector-graphics, raytracing, perspectivecamera

So I am trying to write a Raytracer as a personal project, and I have got the basic recursion, mesh geometry, and ray triangle intersection down.
I am trying to get a plausible image out of it but encounter the problem that all pixel rows are the same, giving me straight vertical lines.

I found that all pixel positions generated from the camera function are the same on the y axis but cannot find the problem with my vector math here (I use my Vertex structure as vectors too, its lazy I know):

```
    void Renderer::CameraShader()
{
    //compute the width and height of the screen based on angle and distance of the near clip plane
    double widthRad = tan(0.5*m_Cam.angle)*m_Cam.nearClipPlane;
    double heightRad = ((double)m_Cam.pixelRows / (double)m_Cam.pixelCols)*widthRad;

    //get the horizontal vector of the camera by crossing the direction angle with an 
    Vertex cross = ((m_Cam.direction - m_Cam.origin).CrossProduct(Vertex(0, 1, 0)).Normalized(0.0001))*widthRad;
    //get the up/down vector of the camera by crossing the horizontal vector with the direction vector
    Vertex crossDown = m_Cam.direction.CrossProduct(cross).Normalized(0.0001)*heightRad;

    //generate rays per pixel row and column
    for (int i = 0; i < m_Cam.pixelCols;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_Cam.pixelRows; j++)
        {
            Vertex pixelPos = m_Cam.origin + (m_Cam.direction - m_Cam.origin).Normalized(0.0001)*m_Cam.nearClipPlane    //vector of the screen center
                - cross + (cross*((i / (double)m_Cam.pixelCols)*widthRad*2))         //horizontal vector based on i
                + crossDown - (crossDown*((j / (double)m_Cam.pixelRows)*heightRad*2));         //vertical vector based on j

            //cast a ray through according screen pixel to get color
            m_Image[i][j] = raycast(m_Cam.origin, pixelPos - m_Cam.origin, p_MaxBounces);
        } 
    }
}
```

I hope the comments in the code make clear what is happening.

If anyone sees the problem help would be nice

Comment: Did you find anything unusual while running it in a debugger? Is `crossDown` correct? Is `m_Image` supposed to be indexed by `[x][y]`? Most graphics APIs take pixels ordered by `[y][x]`.

Comment: And just like that you brought me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had to substract the camera origin from the direction point. It now actually renders sillouettes, so I guess I can say its fixed :)